# TypeError: Failed to construct 'URL': Invalid URL

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm

Iam trying to run the below code, but I am getting TypeError: Failed to construct 'URL': Invalid URL

```
  const handleClick = (movie) => {
    if(trailerUrl){
        setTrailerUrl("")
    }else{
        movieTrailer(movie?.name || "")
            .then((url) => {
                // https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uKrQj_ht3F8
                const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(new URL(url).search)
                setTrailerUrl(urlParams.get("v"))
            })
            .catch((error) => console.log(error))
    }
  }
```

```js
const url = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uKrQj_ht3F8"
const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(new URL(url).search)
console.log(urlParams.get("v"))
```

Comment: add code of `movieTrailer` that we can see what it returns

Comment: Since hardcoded value is working `new URL('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uKrQj_ht3F8')` the problem is with the return value of `movieTrailer` function.

Comment: BTW you can get `URLSearchParams` instance from `URL` instance `new URL('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uKrQj_ht3F8').searchParams.get('v')`

Comment: are you sure console logging url before declaring urlParams is giving the correct output?

Comment: I got this suddently out of nowhere... my dev env is so slow and so bad using Homestead its incredible... i were visiting the same exact page, 2 minutes ago...